# How to add DoubleClick Event To List Box

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

I have a asp `Listbox` Control as

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lstBox" runat="server" CssClass="listBox"></asp:ListBox>
```

I want to add a doubleclick event to the **Listbox** I want a popup. I have googled it and haven't found any of my requirement.

Is there any event that captures the **DoubleClick** event. If not any alternatives to achieve this.

By the way I want to do it everything on the server side and I'm doing it in `WebForm`

Comment: you want to get the item selected with on  the click right?

Comment: Not the selected item or so, when I double click I just want to open a popup

Comment: alright see my answer please.

Answer (score 0):

Well use a hidden input field here to indentify when ever the listbox was clicked:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<script runat="server">
void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e){
if(Request.Params["ListBox1Hidden"] != null
&& (string)Request.Params["ListBox1Hidden"] == "doubleclicked") {
//This means It was double click
Response.Write("Double Click was fired selected item is " 
+ ListBox1.SelectedItem.Text);
   }
}

 </script>
<html>
<head>

<title></title>
<script lang="javascript">
    function ListBox1_DoubleClick() {
        /* we will change value of this hidden field so 
                 that in 
                 page load event we can identify event.
                        */

        document.forms[0].ListBox1Hidden.value = "doubleclicked";
        document.forms[0].submit();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="Form1" runat="server">

        <asp:ListBox id="ListBox1" 
                ondblclick="ListBox1_DoubleClick()" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Value="1">One</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2">Two</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="3">Three</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="4">Four</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:ListBox>
        <input type="hidden" name="ListBox1Hidden" />



</form>
```

Comment: It doesn't have `MouseDoubleClick` event @Slashy

Comment: @hachitti wait.. you only want to display a pop up after it? why you done use javascript for this? would a javascript method help in this case?

Comment: I want to add some data to it, which I want to do it on server side @Slashy

Comment: I told you I want to do it on my `cs` page not on my aspx @Slashy

Comment: @hachitti but it's a server side , you could get the data from the function  `void Page_Load`..

Answer (score 0):

You can add double click event on page load to listbox and can detect double click on page load as below code.

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lstitem" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
```

page load

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            { 
               if (Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"] != null && Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"] == "lstdbclick")
                {
                   //your popup code here
                }
                lstitem.Attributes.Add("ondblclick", ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(lstitem, "lstdbclick"));
            }
```